# Sitecore 10.1.1 installation issue - failed to start service 'Sitecore xconnect search indexer'

Tags: xconnect, installation

I have failed to install `Sitecore 10.1.1` on my local.

I've tried giving full permission to users.

The license I believe is okay as well.

There are the logs from the event viewer. Did anyone encounter this issue before?

```
Application: Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at ‫‍‌​⁭‫‏⁭‏‭⁪‎‮‪⁬‎⁯‪⁪‫⁪‫‏‫‌‎‭‎⁫​⁭‪‫‭‌‏‮⁮‮⁮‮.‎⁬⁬⁫​‪⁪⁪‎‭⁬⁬‪‫⁬‭⁬‭‬‎⁪⁮⁭‪⁯⁭⁬‏⁬⁫⁫‪‮‌⁬‮‫⁬⁯‭‮(‭‪‌‏‪‌⁮⁭‬‎⁪‎‌‍⁫‮⁭‍⁮‫⁬​‏‫‏​⁯⁮‮‏⁯‍‏⁫⁭‮‬⁫⁪‎‮ , String )
   at ‭‪‌‏‪‌⁮⁭‬‎⁪‎‌‍⁫‮⁭‍⁮‫⁬​‏‫‏​⁯⁮‮‏⁯‍‏⁫⁭‮‬⁫⁪‎‮..ctor(String )
   at ⁫‬‮‍‎⁪⁮‍​⁭⁯⁭‭⁬⁬⁯‎⁪‮⁫‮‪‏⁫‮⁬‏⁭‌‪⁭‎‭‌⁪⁯‍‭‪‬‮..ctor(String )
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.InitializeLicenseCheck(IServiceCollection collection, String licenseFileOrXml)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.UseXConnectServiceInitializationConfiguration(IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration configuration, String[] configurationSectionNames, String initializationSectionName, Boolean validateConfiguration)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.ServiceProviderFactory.GetDiServiceProvider(IConfiguration config, String modelDirectory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHostDependencies..ctor(IConfigurationRoot config)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.String, System.String)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.CreateAppDomainAndIndexer()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.CreateAndStartIndexerInNewAppDomain()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.Start()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Service.OnStart(System.String[])
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[])
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.RunAsService(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.InitializeConfigurationAndRun(System.Action`1<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot>)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue recently. 2 solutions I can suggest -

1. `Disable TLS 1.3` over TCP for xconnect. Rerun the installation script or disable this as soon as the xconnect bindings are setup by script during installation. for reference - https://sandeeppote.com/2021/11/14/step-by-step-guide-to-install-sitecore-xp-10-2-using-sif-on-windows-11/

[image]

2. After applying the above changes still I faced the issue so I `uninstall WAC`. After this, I started the installation again and it was successful.