# Sitecore 9.3 installation error Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: xconnect, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I am trying to install `Sitecore 9.3` but getting below error

[image]

Then I tried to view the complete error by executing `Sitecore.MAEngine.exe`, this gives the below error

[image]

```
Error initializing XConnect client. System.AggregateException: One or
more errors occurred. --->
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred
while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
An error occurred while sending the request. --->
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:443
```

Please Help.

Comment: Did you try this? - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en

Comment: Yes I tried but no luck. I also ran the PS command but did not found any non-self-signed certificates

Comment: Can you try by installing with a new name.

Comment: Can you try below link for resolve this issue
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32463/sitecore-10-1-1-installation-issue-failed-to-start-service-sitecore-xconnect/32464#32464

Comment: Can you confirm XConnect collection instance is running? or if any exceptions in logs there?

Comment: If this is for a local machine setup and you dont intend to use marketing automation service, you can edit the xconnect-xp0.json file, find StartServices task and remove the params to start the marketing automation service. This will allow you to complete the Sitecore installation. Basically we are removing the task to start the service as part of the installation. This will unblock you but the correct fix for this issue still should be fixing the certs.

Comment: It looks like your firewall is creating the issue. You need to try that first before checking all the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix which I applied for this issue was to make an entry of localhost default IP address in netsh (which somehow got removed, so the connection was getting refused),
This is the command

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```